# Can one manufacturer's uefi updater/flasher (.exe) be used for other manufacturers' devices?

Tags: uefi, firmware, flashing, steam-deck

https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamDeck/comments/tyuu84/comment/i3vfve2/

According to this comment, it is okay to "grab a Lenovo uefi update pack" and extract the .exe uefi flasher from it, then use the said .exe flasher to flash firmware for the steam deck.

Any problems if doing something like this?

Comment: If you get the firmware wrong, your system is bricked. It's fixable but not trivial, involving special hardware.

Comment: Definitely maybe, if the flashing program is smart enough, the flash chip is at the same address and port and has the same configuration, size, internal arrangement and other features match up. Laptops and the Steam Deck share a common architecture of a SoM (System on Module) architecture so if valve and Lenovo followed the same guide from AMD and didn't deviate or customise it too much then the same tool might work on both. As gronostaj says though if you run a Lenovo tool on the Steam Deck then Valve would be entirely within their rights to refuse any warranty claim for damage you cause.

Comment: This works when the manufacturer makes the EUFI for both systems. This isn't uncommon. But, simply being the same manufacturer or model doesn't mean it will work safely. You should only do this if you know what you're doing and are willing to accept the risks.

Answer (score 3):

**Sometimes, at your own risk.**

Most hardware manufacturers don't build their own UEFIs, but license them from companies specialized in creating UEFIs and customize them for a particular product. Different hardware based on the same UEFI platform will likely share the flashing software.

In this particular case it seems that both Steam Deck and some Lenovo hardware are based on Insyde H2O UEFI.

**By following this procedure you're taking the responsibility for any problems. They won't be covered by the warranty.**

UEFIs themselves aren't interchangeable, with very rare exceptions, and even then patches will be required.